# Keras model always predicting the same class

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, bioinformatics

I am working on a project where I have to classify genomic sequences as either positive or negative. So basically, I have sequences that are in the form 'accccttttttgggg...'
These sequences are 150 characters long consisting of a, c, t and g characters. I perform one hot encoding of the data and create a dataframe that contains 600 columns (150 x 4) for sequences plus one column for label (either 0 or 1). I then pass this data through CNN. The model performs well on the training and validation data but when I see the predictions on test data it always predicts a single label 0. Can anyone help me know why does this happen and what I am doing wrong here. This is the model that I have been using with `epochs=50`, `learning_rate=0.00001` and `batch_size=64`

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(600, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Conv1D(16, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Conv1D(8, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adam = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: is it possible that most of the labels are 0 in the training set?

Comment: Given that it is a time series problem you should try a LSTM network. As for the failure, case, if you could please provide a class distribution of the training data, it will be very helpful to see what is really happening with the model.

Comment: @ZLi I checked the distribution. But it is not the case that most of the labels are 0. I am using a dataset of size 80k values with 40k labels being positive and 40k negative. Even after splitting into train, validation and test set the distribution remains almost constant.